# Snowflake SPLIT_PART Function not returning Null values

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Below is the sample data in the JSON file

'Desktop::abc:voip::GET STARTED' as Col1

When I run the below query in the Snowflake the value for second_value is shown as blank instead of NULL Value. How I can get NULL value for this sample data

```
select  'Desktop::abc:voip::GET STARTED' as Col1
        split_part($1:Col1 :: String, ':', 1) as First_Value,
        split_part($1:Col1 :: String, ':', 2)  as Second_Value,
        split_part($1:Col1 :: String, ':', 3) as Third_Value,
        split_part($1:Col1 :: String, ':', 4) as Fourth_Value;
```

Output as below

[image]

Comment: Do you really want to get NULL or parse this data correctly? for example, first value is Dekstop, second one is abc etc...

Comment: you can directly refer to col1 in in the split_part so it can be written as `split_part(Col1, ':', 1)`

Comment: Also the wording "show as blank instead of NULL" implies you expect NULL, where-as split is doing it's job correctly, the 'second' sub-string, which exists, it just happens to be zero length, which is quite different to not existing, I might expect NULL is you asked for the tenth split as it does not exist (but testing shows it also gives empty string). So checking you understand why you are getting the empty string. Because if you understand the presence of empty string, you can work as effectively with that as with null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can coerce zero-length strings into NULLS with NULLIF().  For example:

```
select  'Desktop::abc:voip::GET STARTED' as Col1,
NULLiF(split_part(Col1 :: String, ':', 1),'') as First_Value,
NULLiF(split_part(Col1 :: String, ':', 2),'') as Second_Value,
NULLiF(split_part(Col1 :: String, ':', 3),'') as Third_Value,        
NULLiF(split_part(Col1 :: String, ':', 4),'') as Fourth_Value
```